# Vbscript to replace a special value with the previous value in a csv file with multiple columns

Tags: csv, replace, vbscript

i have a csv file like this:

```
Date;Time:From;To;Column1;Column2;Column3;Column4;
27.07.2015;07:00+01;07:15+01;10;3.23506;0;3.23506;
27.07.2015;07:15+01;07:30+01;15;3.22012;0;3.22012;
27.07.2015;07:30+01;07:45+01;10;3.4916;0;3.4916;
27.07.2015;07:45+01;08:00+01;34;3.86548;0;3.86548;
27.07.2015;08:00+01;08:15+01;undef;5.1987;0;5.1987;
27.07.2015;08:15+01;08:30+01;undef;6.66222;0;6.66222;
27.07.2015;08:30+01;08:45+01;undef;6.88191;0;6.88191;
27.07.2015;08:45+01;09:00+01;undef;6.91766;0;6.91766;
27.07.2015;09:00+01;09:15+01;17;3.86548;0;3.86548;
27.07.2015;09:15+01;09:30+01;undef;3.86548;0;3.86548;
27.07.2015;09:30+01;09:45+01;25;3.86548;0;3.86548;
```

How is it possible to replace the "undef" value with the last real value?

The Result should look like this:

```
Date;Time:From;To;Column1;Column2;Column3;Column4;
27.07.2015;07:00+01;07:15+01;10;3.23506;0;3.23506;
27.07.2015;07:15+01;07:30+01;15;3.22012;0;3.22012;
27.07.2015;07:30+01;07:45+01;10;3.4916;0;3.4916;
27.07.2015;07:45+01;08:00+01;34;3.86548;0;3.86548;
27.07.2015;08:00+01;08:15+01;34;5.1987;0;5.1987;
27.07.2015;08:15+01;08:30+01;34;6.66222;0;6.66222;
27.07.2015;08:30+01;08:45+01;34;6.88191;0;6.88191;
27.07.2015;08:45+01;09:00+01;34;6.91766;0;6.91766;
27.07.2015;09:00+01;09:15+01;17;3.86548;0;3.86548;
27.07.2015;09:15+01;09:30+01;17;3.86548;0;3.86548;
27.07.2015;09:30+01;09:45+01;25;3.86548;0;3.86548;
```

The script should also work if the undef is on an another position or the csv file has more columns.

Did anyone has an idea?

BR
Klausn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the first - hopefully complete - line to fill the gaps in the next line and use that for the next step:

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS  : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim tsIn  : Set tsIn = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\31557923.csv")
tsIn.SkipLine ' skip header (and two EOF checks and a check for undef in first line)
Dim aData : aData = Split(tsIn.ReadLine(), ";")
WScript.Echo Join(aData, ";")
Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
   Dim aLine : aLine = Split(tsIn.ReadLine(), ";")
   Dim i
   For i = 0 To UBound(aData)
       If "undef" = aLine(i) Then aLine(i) = aData(i)
   Next
   aData = aLine
   WScript.Echo Join(aData, ";")
Loop
tsIn.Close
```

output:

```
cscript 31557923.vbs
27.07.2015;07:00+01;07:15+01;10;3.23506;0;3.23506;
27.07.2015;07:15+01;07:30+01;15;3.22012;0;3.22012;
27.07.2015;07:30+01;07:45+01;10;3.4916;0;3.4916;
27.07.2015;07:45+01;08:00+01;34;3.86548;0;3.86548;
27.07.2015;08:00+01;08:15+01;34;5.1987;0;5.1987;
27.07.2015;08:15+01;08:30+01;34;6.66222;0;6.66222;
27.07.2015;08:30+01;08:45+01;34;6.88191;0;6.88191;
27.07.2015;08:45+01;09:00+01;34;6.91766;0;6.91766;
27.07.2015;09:00+01;09:15+01;17;3.86548;0;3.86548;
27.07.2015;09:15+01;09:30+01;17;3.86548;0;3.86548;
27.07.2015;09:30+01;09:45+01;25;3.86548;0;3.86548;
```

**Update:**

A version that handles the header correctly and uses known default data for the first line:

```
Option Explicit

Sub checkEOF(tsIn)
  If tsIn.AtEndOfStream Then
     WScript.Echo "Incomplete file"
     WScript.Quit 1
  End If
End Sub


Dim goFS  : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim tsIn  : Set tsIn = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\31557923-2.csv")
checkEOF tsIn
WScript.Echo tsIn.ReadLine()
checkEOF tsIn
Dim aData : aData = Split("27.07.2015;07:15+01;07:30+01;15;3.22012;0;3.22012;", ";")
Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
   Dim aLine : aLine = Split(tsIn.ReadLine(), ";")
   Dim i
   For i = 0 To UBound(aData)
       If "undef" = aLine(i) Then aLine(i) = aData(i)
   Next
   aData = aLine
   WScript.Echo Join(aData, ";")
Loop
tsIn.Close
```

Comment: one problem is found ... the first row is missing in the export file

Comment: i have a 3 row header ... after the script is run the export file has only a 2 row header where the first row is missing.

Comment: @Klausn - read and write the first line instead of skipping it as I did in the demo.

Comment: i removed the skipping, but the first row is still missing.